# Improving the Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The Riemann mapping theorem states that a connected simply-connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ or the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$.

After studying its proof, I am wondering whether one can actually prove the following stronger statement:

> > Let $\Omega\neq \mathbb{C}$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that every holomorphic function on $\Omega$ has a (holomorphic) primitive and that every non-vanishing holomorphic function on $\Omega$ has a square root. Then $\Omega$ is biholomorphic to the open unit disc.

Comment: In which way is that statement stronger? Each of the statements “every holomorphic function on $\Omega$ has a (holomorphic) primitive” and “every non-vanishing holomorphic function on $\Omega$ has a square root” is equivalent to the assertion that $\Omega$ is simply-connected.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  I didn't know that. I know that simply connected implies those two properties, but how does one show that, say, "every non-vanishing holomorphic function on $\Omega $ has a square root" implies "$\Omega$ is simply connected"?

Comment: Take a look at John B. Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable I*, chapter VIII, theorem 2.2. By the way, Conway says that “This theorem constitutes an aesthetic peak in Mathematics”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That is absolutely amazing...(It's Theorem 3.2 in the version I have btw.)